# Find rows with a group values from other table

Tags: sql, subquery

| id | role | Group_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 |
| 2 | B | 1 |
| 3 | A | 2 |
| 4 | D | 2 |
| 5 | A | 3 |
| 6 | B | 3 |
| 7 | C | 3 |
| 8 | C | 4 |

...

| User_id | role |
| --- | --- |
| user1 | A |
| user1 | B |
| user2 | C |
| user2 | D |
| user3 | A |
| user3 | D |
| user4 | C |
| user5 | A |
| user5 | B |
| user5 | C |
| user5 | D |

...

I have 2 tables Table1 and Table2 as shown above.
My requirement is to get the User_ID from the table2 which has all the roles from a group. Additionally, only those groups need to be checked which has at least 2 roles. If a group_ID has only 1 role then it should not be considered

For example, this is how the result will look like from above 2 tables

user1 has both the roles from group 1 (A,B) -> therefore it is in the results.

user3 has both the roles from group 2 (A,D) -> therefore it is in the results.

user5 has all the roles from group 1(A,B), 2(A,D) and 3(A,B,C) -> therefore it is in the results.

User2 has role C and D which is not a group, hence not shown in the result

User4 has role C which is a group (Group_ID = 4), but the group should have at least 2 roles, hence not shown in the result

| User_id | Group_ID |
| --- | --- |
| user1 | 1 |
| user3 | 2 |
| user5 | 1 |
| user5 | 2 |
| user5 | 3 |

....

```
Select Table2.USER_ID,Table1.GROUP_ID 
from Table2, 
     Table1 
Where Table2.ROLE =  Table1.ROLE
group by Table1.GROUP_ID,Table2.USER_ID
```

With the above query, I am able to get the records with user_id assigned any of the role. However, I want to get the User_ID from the table2 which has all the roles from a group.

Any help is much appreciated. I will also make sure to accept the answer leading me to the solution

Comment: A) Specifically which *one* of the dbms's listed are you using? B) Could you post an example of the expected results? Try and include a user that "has all the roles from a group"  ... and one that doesn't.

Comment: You keep editing your post, but haven't answered a critical question yet: What is your database product? MySQL? Microsoft SQL Server? Oracle Database? Something else? (And don't say "it doesn't matter", because it does!)

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am using both Oracle and SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A direct translation of the requirement into SQL (Oracle style)

```
with g as (
select group_id, count(*) role_cnt from table1 group by group_id having count(*) > 1),
u as (
select u.user_id, g.group_id, count(*) usergroup_role_cnt from table1 g, table2 u
where u.role=g.role
group by u.user_id, g.group_id)
select u.user_id, g.group_id from g, u
where u.group_id=g.group_id
and u.usergroup_role_cnt=g.role_cnt;
```

**Edit:**

There has been concern about query performance using "group by" when tables are "very large". I don't know how "very large" is defined. Anyway, I did a test on Oracle Clould Free Tier ATP database 19c, using tables with tens of thousand rows. Here is the result.

```
select count(*) from table1;

COUNT(*) 
-------- 
  289327 


Elapsed: 00:00:00.007
1 rows selected.


select count(*) from table2;

COUNT(*) 
-------- 
 1445328 


Elapsed: 00:00:00.024
1 rows selected.


with g as (
select group_id, count(*) role_cnt from table1 group by group_id having count(*) > 1),
u as (
select u.user_id, g.group_id, count(*) usergroup_role_cnt from table1 g, table2 u
where u.role=g.role
group by u.user_id, g.group_id)
select u.user_id, g.group_id from g, u
where u.group_id=g.group_id
and u.usergroup_role_cnt=g.role_cnt;


USER_ID GROUP_ID 
------- -------- 
user99       994 
user97       462 
user97       199 
user87        35 
user99       462 
user87       179 
user99       199 
user98       199 
user96       199 
user87       813 
user87       941 
user96       994 
user97       994 
user96       462 
user98       462 
user98       994 


Elapsed: 00:00:04.770
16 rows selected.

select a2.user_id, a1.group_id
from   (
         select user_id, cast(collect(role) as role_list) as user_roles
         from   table2
         group  by user_id
       ) a2
       inner join
       (
         select group_id, cast(collect(role) as role_list) as group_roles
         from   table1
         group  by group_id
       ) a1
       on a1.group_roles submultiset of a2.user_roles
order  by user_id, group_id
;

USER_ID GROUP_ID 
------- -------- 
user87        35 
user87       179 
user87       813 
user87       941 
user96       199 
user96       462 
user96       994 
user97       199 
user97       462 
user97       994 
user98       199 
user98       462 
user98       994 
user99       199 
user99       462 
user99       994 


Elapsed: 00:01:35.395
16 rows selected.

select q2.user_id, q1.group_id
from   (select distinct user_id  from table2) q2
       cross join
       (select distinct group_id from table1) q1
where  not exists 
       (
         select role
         from   table1
         where  group_id = q1.group_id
           and  role not in
                     (
                       select role
                       from   table2
                       where  user_id = q2.user_id
                     )
       )
order  by user_id, group_id
;

(Manually cancelled after 10 min)
```

Data is generated quite randomly and is somewhat skewed. But in reality, skewed data is not avoidable. Statistics should minimize the impact. (Both tables were analyzed and have no indexes)

Comment: Thank you for responding. This works!!
I am validating it with more use cases and will get back

Comment: This does work, but it may take a very long time if the tables are very large. "group by" is the most expensive operation in this query (and in many others). It is one thing to aggregate each table separately (as I do in my answers - either to create the role lists, in the first solution, or to get the distinct id's in the second; that step in the second solution shouldn't be needed). It is a different thing to aggregate over the join of the two tables, which may be orders of magnitude greater than each table. Of course, the OP's data may not be too big, so this wouldn't matter.

Comment: '"group by" is slow' doesn't mean 'no "group by" is fast', at least according to my test.

Comment: I have accepted this as a correct solution as it is much faster, works on both Oracle and SQL Server perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that will work in Oracle Database; adapt it for SQL Server (if that is possible; I don't know that dialect).

Test data (others may use this too):

```
create table table1(id number, role varchar2(10), group_id number);

insert into table1 (id, role, group_id)
    select 1, 'A', 1 from dual union all
    select 2, 'B', 1 from dual union all
    select 3, 'A', 2 from dual union all
    select 4, 'D', 2 from dual union all
    select 5, 'A', 3 from dual union all
    select 6, 'B', 3 from dual union all
    select 7, 'C', 3 from dual
;

create table table2 (user_id varchar2(20), role varchar2(10));

insert into table2 (user_id, role)
    select 'user1', 'A' from dual union all
    select 'user1', 'B' from dual union all
    select 'user2', 'C' from dual union all
    select 'user2', 'D' from dual union all
    select 'user3', 'A' from dual union all
    select 'user3', 'D' from dual union all
    select 'user4', 'C' from dual union all
    select 'user5', 'A' from dual union all
    select 'user5', 'B' from dual union all
    select 'user5', 'C' from dual union all
    select 'user5', 'D' from dual
;

commit;
```

Create user-defined data type (collection of strings representing roles):

```
create or replace type role_list as table of varchar2(10);
/
```

Query and output:

```
select a2.user_id, a1.group_id
from   (
         select user_id, cast(collect(role) as role_list) as user_roles
         from   table2
         group  by user_id
       ) a2
       inner join
       (
         select group_id, cast(collect(role) as role_list) as group_roles
         from   table1
         group  by group_id
       ) a1
       on a1.group_roles submultiset of a2.user_roles
order  by user_id, group_id
;

USER_ID         GROUP_ID
------------  ----------
user1                  1
user3                  2
user5                  1
user5                  2
user5                  3
```

The strategy is pretty obvious, and should be easy to read directly from the code. Group the roles by `group_id` in the first table and by `user_id` in the second. Identify all the pairs (user, group) where all roles for the group are found in the role list of the user - that is exactly what the `submultiset` comparison operator does.

A more rudimentary query (harder to follow and maintain, and likely slower), but perhaps helpful as it is likely to work with very few changes - if any - in pretty much all SQL dialects, might look like this. Assuming `role` can't be `null` in `table2` (to make the query slightly simpler):

```
select q2.user_id, q1.group_id
from   (select distinct user_id  from table2) q2
       cross join
       (select distinct group_id from table1) q1
where  not exists 
       (
         select role
         from   table1
         where  group_id = q1.group_id
           and  role not in
                     (
                       select role
                       from   table2
                       where  user_id = q2.user_id
                     )
       )
order  by user_id, group_id
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the ans. Is it possible to update the query without creating a new table - role_list  ?
Additionally, only those groups need to be checked which has at least 2 roles. If a group_ID has only 1 role then it should not be considered.

Comment: @Ashutosh - Consider the second query, it may be closer to your needs. To only consider groups with at least two roles, change the definition of subquery `q1` to: `(select group_id from table1 group by group_id having count(*) > 1) q1` (assuming the roles are non-null and distinct for each group).

Comment: can you please explain the 2nd solution ? I thought I figured it out but I am little confuse now

Comment: @Ashutosh - The two subqueries at the top of the query select all distinct user id's and group id's. This step shouldn't be needed - you should have separate, smaller tables (sometimes called "dimension" tables) with info about users and groups, respectively - with `user_id` and `group_id` as primary keys. Then the query looks for all pairs (user, group) where there is no role for the group in `table2`, that is not also a role for the user in `table1`. Exactly as you need.